# IsMouseOver overlaps with IsSelected for ListViewItem

Tags: wpf

I defined style for templated listboxitem (here is the part of it):

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Cornsilk"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Unfortunetly, when I select some item, it still remains as IsMouseOver defines it.  I have to move mouse out of the box for it to become Azure.  May be something is missing?  Perhaps there is a way to make some style an overriding one (IsSelected)?
Thanks.

Comment: This is bad design. You should not set the background by triggers on properties that are not exclusive. If both IsSelected and IsMouseOver are true, which background shall be set? It's ambiguous.

Comment: To set the one that is more prerogative)  But I have no idea if wpf supports such an idea.  But how would you go about implementing the descibed scenario then?

Comment: May be MultiDatatrigger is the one I want, no?  So I could specify combination of properties and their values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of your triggers. When two conditions are the same, only the last one applies.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Cornsilk"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I achieved this by using MultiTriggers, instead of Triggers.

```
 <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />

                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedListboxItem}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />

                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoveredListboxItem}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the Background property in the triggers of non-exclusive properties `IsSelected` and `IsMouseOver` and thus create an ambiguous value.

Instead you could put a Cornsilk-colored Rectangle with `Opacity="0"` above all other controls in your template, and in the `IsMouseOver` trigger set the Rectangle's `Opacity` to e.g. 0.5. Thus you can visualize both states at the same time, since you can still see the `IsSelected`-colored background through the semi-transparent `IsMouseOver` Rectangle.